# Why can't I get the Windows installer to launch (Bootcamp)? iMac 13, 1 (late 2012)

Tags: bootcamp

I get a black screen with blinking cursor when Boot Camp reboots after creating the partition.  I have been trying to install Windows 10 1909 on an iMac 13,1 (late 2012) running High Sierra (and now Catalina). The first issue I had was creating the USB - I ran into the issue that boot camp could not create the USB because there is a file greater than 4 GB, and so I circumvented this issue by re-formatting the USB to exFAT and then copying the contents of the Windows software support and the Windows 10 ISO onto the drive.  I also read some reports that you need a USB 2.0, and so I've attempted that as well with the same result.

I then run boot camp and create a partition, and the system reboots, but just has a black screen with blinking cursor, so I cannot not run the Windows installer at all. If I manual shutdown and then reboot holding option, I have a USB option "Windows" and "EFI Boot" (or at least that was the way it was with High Sierra). When I run EFI Boot, I can enter the Windows installer, but an EFI windows install is not possible because the partition scheme is MBR, not GPT (and I've heard the drivers for this generation Mac do not cooperate with EFI boot anyway). When I run "Windows" option, I get the same result - black screen with blinking cursor. So I am stuck.

I'm not certain if this is relevant, but this machine previously had Windows 10 dual boot with its original Mountain Lion install, however, the Windows install completely crashed and was irreparable. What I did was remove the Windows partition with Boot camp assistant, and then I completely wiped MacOS and re-installed the High Sierra. I did run updates, and it did run a firmware update.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The High Sierra installer has firmware updates the are newer than any update you can download from Apple. So how is it that you have installed a firmware update after installing High Sierra?

Comment: There was a firmware update available that updated my Mountain Lion firmware to High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac is suppose to EFI boot 64 bit Windows 10. You should not be using hybrid partitioning when installing Windows 10. You should use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software. If you copied the Window Support Software correctly to the flash drive, then there should be a `$WinPEDriver$` folder in the root folder of the flash drive. You should be able to remove hybrid partitioning  by using the Disk Utility application to `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` format the internal partition where you intend to install Windows. Or, you can use the `diskutil` command to `JHFS+` format. You should EFI boot from the flash drive to install Windows 10.

### The Problem

You view the Boot Camp partition in the Disk Utility and you see the partition contains either a `MS‑DOS (FAT32)` or `ExFAT` volume, as shown below.

[image]

When installing Windows, you will encounter the following error message.

[image]

This is a indication that the installation drive is hybrid partitioned. You need to remove hybrid partitioning in order to install Windows to UEFI boot.

### Solution Method 1

If an action by the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command results in no Microsoft specific partitions existing on a drive, then High Sierra and newer versions of macOS will remove hybrid partitioning. Since there is only one Microsoft specific partition on this drive, the drive will be erased and formatted `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` by the Disk Utility to remove the hybrid partitioning. The result is shown below.

[image]

When installing Windows you will encounter the following error message.

[image]

A solution is to follow the steps given below.

1. Highlight the partition where you were going to install Windows, then select the `Delete` button and the `OK` button.
2. Highlight the unallocated space, then select the `New` button followed by the `Apply` and `OK` buttons. The result is shown below.

   [image]
3. (Optional)  Since the Boot Camp Assistant has always omitted the `MSR (Reserved)` partition when I have installed Windows to UEFI boot, I will delete this partition. Feel free to leave the partition, if you wish.

   > Note: Microsoft documentation states there should always be an `MSR (Reserved)` partition.
4. Highlight the partition where you wish to install Windows, as shown below.

   [image]
5. Select the `Next` button to install Windows. The installer will automatically `NTFS` format the partition.

### Solution Method 2

If an action by the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command results in no Microsoft specific partitions existing on a drive, then High Sierra and newer versions of macOS will remove hybrid partitioning. Since there is only one Microsoft specific partition on this drive, the drive will be erased and formatted `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` by the Disk Utility to remove the hybrid partitioning. The result is shown below.

[image]

When installing Windows you encounter the following error message.

[image]

A solution is to follow the steps given below.

1. Press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination to open a Command Prompt window. Enter the commands shown below.  If your drive and partition numbers are different, then make the appropriate substitutions. The last `exit` command will close the window.

   [image]
2. Select the `Refresh` button.
3. Highlight the partition where you want to instal Windows, as shown below.

   [image]
4. Select the `Next` button to install Windows. The installer will automatically `NTFS` format the partition.

### Solution Method 3

If an action by the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command results in no Microsoft specific partitions existing on a drive, then High Sierra and newer versions of macOS will remove hybrid partitioning. Since there is only one Microsoft specific partition on this drive, the drive will be erased and formatted `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` by the Disk Utility to remove the hybrid partitioning. The result is shown below.

[image]

To avoid the problems encountered with the first two methods, the partition will be erased and `ExFAT` formatted by the Disk Utility application. The result is shown below. With High Sierra and newer versions of macOS, the drive will not be hybrid partitioned by this action.

[image]

When installing Windows you encounter the following error message.

[image]

The solution is to select the `Format` button to `NTFS` format the partition. The result is shown below.

[image]

You can now select the `Next` button to proceed and install Windows.

### A Note About Partitioning

There are two unique partition tables stored on a drive where macOS is installed. The first is a legacy Master Boot Record (MBR) table. This table is ignored by macOS. The second is a GUID Partition Table (GPT). If there are partition entries in the MBR table, then Windows with use this table and ignore the GPT. This is referred to a hybrid partitioning. If a UEFI booted Graphical User Interface (GUI) Windows installer detects partition entries in the MBR partition table on a drive, then the installer will not install Windows on that drive. In your case, hybrid partitioning needs to be removed from the internal drive in order to install a UEFI booting Windows 10.

Comment: I did copy the Windows support software to the flash drive as you suggest, including the WinPED driver that you mention.  Do I need to format the Windows partition manually?  Isn't Windows supposed to use NTFS partitioning?

Comment: ...or is it that Windows will re-format the partition during installation to NTFS?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You use macOS to ExFAT format. Later, you use the Windows installer to NTFS format.

Comment: When I use diskutil list, it lists my disk as a GUID_partition_Scheme; however, when I launch the Windows Installer, it states that I cannot install because this disk uses MBR partitioning?  Why is that?  Is GUID_partition_scheme not the same as GPT?

Comment: I update my answer to answer the questions in your previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Instead of `ExFAT`, you should the `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` format to remove hybrid partitioning. The macOS operating system will remove hybrid partitioning on a drive when there are no `Microsoft Basic Data` types on the drive. The types can be viewed by using the command `diskutil list`.

Comment: I reformatted the partition in disk utility to Mac OS extended (journaled), and then rebooted into the Windows installer; however, I do not have the option to re-format that partition back to NTFS within the installer.  The format option is grayed out.  The explanation of why Windows cannot install is "This volume must be NTFS to install.  This is an unrecognized format"

Comment: I suppose the only way to answer the question is to simulate the problem. Otherwise a mistake or two will creep into an answer. I posted three possible answers that were simulated using VirtualBox.

Comment: Deleting the partition and re-creating the new partition in the installer has worked (so far) - I was able to launch the installation process, and we'll see how it goes.  Thank you for your commitment!

Comment: Separate question - how do I run the Windows support software?  I did not complete Windows setup yet, but the installation process appears to have been successful.  I was going to complete the setup at my office since it will be on our network (and is currently at home), but I just wanted to have an idea because I couldn't readily find the answer.

Comment: After Window finishes installing, you need to run the `Setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder on the flash drive. Afterwards, run Apple Software Update until all updates from Apple have been installed.

Comment: Ugh...the bootcamp drivers broke Windows.  After driver installation and restart, it went to blue screen recovery.  I was able to boot into safe mode, but I have no idea which drivers broke Windows.

Comment: How did you acquire the Windows Support Software?

Comment: I downloaded it with bootcamp on the same machine.

Comment: I re-installed Windows and it appears that the hardware functionality is good without installing the Windows Support software.  Is it necessary to install it?  I realize that there isn't a boot camp assistant to set the default boot operating system, but other than that, am I missing out on anything?  I re-downloaded the support software on OS X catalina, but I am a bit nervous to try to attempt to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, years ago. I solved it by changing the Windows installation DVD (a specific one won't install properly). In other words, if you are in trouble creating a Stick, try burning an Installation DVD or try another Windows-Image.

Comment: I don't believe this model even has an optical drive.  I may attempt to re-create the USB, it just took ages to copy the files over USB 2.0

Comment: That‘s true, but u could use a external USB Optical Drive, but u r right try the Stick first